# Node.js - POST request won't execute until end of script

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I'm trying to perform multiple POST requests in my code however the POST request will only occur when the script terminates. So far I've loaded the below code in via a function and imported the function as a module with no success.

I'm relatively new to node.js so I may be missing something obvious here. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    var request = require('request');
    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://XXXXXXXXXX.com/Example',
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Basic SuperSecretPassword',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {
             'To': Receiver,
             'From': Sender,
             'Parameters': '{"Flag":"1","Duration":"5"}'
        }
    };


    request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(response.body);
    });

    console.log(options);
```

Comment: "Node.js runs single-threaded, non-blocking, asynchronous programming", do you understand how to write and use events or await & promises... Things actually all happen kind of at once on node.js unless you specifically set them not to.... read: https://nodejs.dev/learn/javascript-asynchronous-programming-and-callbacks

Comment: Hmm I've had a read through the documents and implemented the promise / await. Still the same problem. The POST request isn't sent until the end of the script even with a 60 second delay added onto the end.